# Squarespace-- how do i change the social media symbol to an image for the mobile version?

Tags: css, hyperlink, squarespace

I was able to change the social media symbol in the navbar on Squarespace to an image in the desktop view. However, it doesn't change it on the mobile version. Here's the code--

.icon--fill:nth-of-type(4) {
svg {
display:none
}
background-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fce72d1a20acc7aeb8a51e1/t/626f0d9afd4cc6667ebbc5a5/1651445146440/Apple-Hover.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

It only goes back to the default image of links. Any ideas?

Comment: If by chance you could add a link to the site/page in question, that may make it easier for others to provide the best answer. Sometimes, of course, providing a link to the page isn't possible.